# How to get system information about HTML5 LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Is it possible to get system information about localstorage with JavaScript?

For example if there are 3 localstorage DBs in the browser:

```
mysite.com
yoursite.com
nobodyssite.come
```

I want to get the count of all the DBs, which is 3

Also is it possible to get the system ID of the DB? I am sure that `mysite.com` DB has some integer ID like `128475`, can I get this with JavaScript?

Comment: What do you mean here by localstorage ? - storage on the client machine or storage on server machine ?

Comment: localstorage like HTML5 storage on the client...

Comment: Just right off the bat, I'm betting this is impossible. Privacy would be against it.

Comment: Can you explain why you want this? What does it matter if there are other localStorage databases stored on a client? Why would you need to know? What service do you (intend to) offer that relies upon this knowledge?

Comment: @DavidThomas The info you ask is a company secret.